# React Component keep size according to parent

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-component

Might be a newbie question, but I struggle to solve it.

I would like to create a web ui using React. 
I have made a component but I don't manage to fix the component's size to its parent container.
I use React and React-bootstrap. The layout of the App.js looks like this.

```
   <div class="p-1 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
      <Container fluid="md">
          <div class="p-1 mb-2 bg-warning text-white">
          <Row>          
            <Col>            
              <p>
                <h2>Header Title</h2>
              </p>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <p class="text-right">
                <h2>Some Header text</h2>
              </p>
            </Col>            
          </Row>
          </div>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <ButtonGroup vertical>
                <Button variant="secondary">Menu1</Button>
                <Button variant="secondary">Menu2</Button>
                <Button variant="secondary">Menu3</Button>
                <Button variant="secondary">Menu4</Button>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Row>
                <MyComponent/>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <ButtonGroup horizontal>
                  <Button>Test</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
              </Row>
            </Col>
          </Row>          
        </Container>      
    </div>
```

The layout should be looking like this

```
---------------------------------------
|Title                       SomeText |
---------------------------------------
|Menu1|                               |
|Menu2|                               |
|Menu3|           MyComponent         |
|Menu4|                               |
|     |-------------------------------|
|     |  TestButtons                  |
---------------------------------------
```

But I cannot get MyComponent to fill and stay within its area.
If I use window.innerWidth / height in the MyComponent when render it,
it gets as large as the complete window and jumps down below the menu buttons looking 
like the below figure instead.

```
---------------------------------------
|Title                       SomeText |
---------------------------------------
|Menu1|                               |
|Menu2|                               |
|Menu3|                               |
|Menu4|                               |
|-------------------------------------|
|               MyComponent           |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
|   TestButtons                       |
---------------------------------------
```

**Question**: How can I force MyComponent to stay in its Row/Column and auto-size to fill the available area from the parent?

**Question**: Obviously the menu  does not fill 100% the height since the MyComponent gets placed underneath it. How can I force it to keep the complete column height.